# Interactions between geometry and graph theory.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, big-list

I'm looking for some nice theories or just exercises, with both geometrical aspects and graph theoretics aspects.

Example may include for instance the 4-color theorem or Euler characteristics, maybe Königsberg's bridges (although this last one is almost purely graph theoretic). Ideally I'm looking for material that is not too advanced, like first year of university.

Comment: The five platonic solids and the dual of each one (another platonic solid).

Comment: yes, the topological proof using Euler characteristic is perfectly in the theme.

Comment: Most of the things I keep thinking of are topological in nature. Like Poincare cubes or gluing flat sheets to get compact surfaces.

Comment: Anything relating Euler characteristic and triangulation. For instance, the classification of compact surfaces.

Comment: Maybe proofs showing $k_{3,3}$ and $k_5$ can not be imbedded in the plane.

Comment: yes I had those thanks :)

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is the crossing number of a graph (or rectilinear crossing number). This might be a case of a concept being easy to explain but hard to prove much about.

Comment: How about the theorem that a convex polyhedron made from hexagonal and pentagonal faces, such that each vertex meets $3$ edges must have exactly $12$ pentagonal faces? Sometimes called the soccer ball theorem.

Comment: as guidelines, here are other problems that fit the question:
-chromatic number of the plane (try to obtain any bounds)
-rectangle with one integer side

Comment: Perhaps the work of Tutte in the embedding of a graph. See "How to draw a graph" Tutte.
Or Hyperplane arrangements, seein by its matroid point of view.

Answer (score 0):

[Oriented matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_matroid) may be a link between geometry and graph theory.